# How much somone expiate for an oath about zina

Tags: tawba, zina, oaths

If somone promises to Allah not to commit zina of eyes, ears etc. But breaks the oath do they have to expiate for each form of zina or just zina as a whole

For example would they have to expiate and fast 3 days for each form of zina

Or would they have to expiate and only fast 3 days for just zina as a whole